Inter system vertical distance in Piano Instrument for Cadence / Tikz configuration
It is needed to configure the Inter system vertical distance in Piano Instrument for Cadence sequence. Maybe the problem is the additional space generated by Tikz. The basic code is as follow:
\documentclass[%
border={1pt -30pt 2pt -1pt},% left bottom right top
%border=8pt
varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\input musixlyr
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\xdefinecolor{red-undar}{RGB}{179,35,79}
\begin{document}
\begin{music}
\hsize=\linewidth%
\font\A=phvb8t at 10pt% added for letter type.
\font\B=phvb8t at 13pt% added for letter type.
\resetlyrics
\setlyrics{Acordes}{\B V \B I \B IV \B I \B V\raisebox{-.1ex}{\bfseries\musFig[l]{6\,5 4\,3}} \empty{} \B I \B IV \B I \empty{} \B V\raisebox{-.1ex}{\bfseries\musFig[l]{4-3 5---}} \empty{} \B I \B IV \B I \B V\raisebox{-.1ex}{\bfseries\musFig[l]{5\,6 3\,4}} \empty{} \B V\raisebox{-.1ex}{\bfseries\musFig[l]{4-3 5---}} \empty{} \B I \B IV \B I}%
\setsongraise{1}{-0.3cm}
\parindent0mm
\sepbarrules
\instrumentnumber{1}%
\interstaff{12}%espacio entre pentagramas del piano
%\stafftopmarg0pt\staffbotmarg5\Interligne\relax%
\setclef16
\setstaffs12
\nobarnumbers
\startpiece
\A\assignlyricsmulti{1}{1}{Acordes}
\notes\hsk\zhl{G}\hu{b}\zcharnote{-24}{\hspace{-2.35cm}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (point) at (0,0)[text width=16mm,align=center] {\textcolor{red-undar}{\A\textbf{}}};
\draw[line width=2pt,draw=red-undar] (0.1,5.3) -- ++(0,0.1)-- ++(-4.1,0) node[midway,above,text width=2.5cm,text centered,] {\textcolor{red-undar}{\A\textbf\centering{Cadencia Perfecta}}}-- ++(0,-0.1);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
|\hsk\zhl{g}\hu{k}\en
\notes\zhl{J}\hu{c}|\zhl{g}\hu{l}\en\setdoublebar\bar%
\notes\zhl{M}\hu{c}\zcharnote{-24}{\hspace{-3.1cm}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (point) at (0,0)[text width=16mm,align=center] {\textcolor{red-undar}{\A\textbf{}}};
\draw[line width=2pt,draw=red-undar] (0.1,5.3) -- ++(0,0.1)-- ++(-6.1,0) node[midway,above = 0.15cm of point,text width=4.6cm,text centered,] {\textcolor{red-undar}{\A\textbf\centering{Cadencia Plagal}}}-- ++(0,-0.1);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
|\zhl{h}\hu{m}\en\bar%
\notes\zhl{J}\hu{c}|\zhl{g}\hu{l}\en\setdoubleBAR\alaligne%
\notes\zwh{G}\hu{e}\zcharnote{-24}{\hspace{-2.4cm}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (point) at (0,0)[text width=16mm,align=center] {\textcolor{red-undar}{\A\textbf{}}};
\draw[line width=2pt,draw=red-undar] (0.1,5.3) -- ++(0,0.1)-- ++(-5.1,0) node[midway,above,text width=5.8cm,text centered,] {\textcolor{red-undar}{\A\textbf\centering{Cadencia Compuesta\\ Consonante}}}-- ++(0,-0.1);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
|\zwh{g}\hu{j}\en%
\notes\hu{d}|\hu{i}\en\bar%
\notes\zhl{J}\hu{e}|\zhl{g}\hu{j}\en%
\notes\zhl{M}\hu{f}\zcharnote{-24}{\hspace{-2.9cm}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (point) at (0,0)[text width=16mm,align=center] {\textcolor{red-undar}{\A\textbf{}}};
\draw[line width=2pt,draw=red-undar] (0.1,5.3) -- ++(0,0.1)-- ++(-4.8,0) node[midway,above = 0.15cm of point,text width=5.8cm,text centered,] {\textcolor{red-undar}{\A\textbf\centering{Cadencia Plagal}}}-- ++(0,-0.1);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
|\zhl{h}\hu{j}\en\bar%
\notes\zwh{J}\wh{e}|\zwh{g}\wh{j}\en\setdoubleBAR\alaligne%
\notes\issluru0c\hu{c}\zcharnote{-24}{\hspace{-1.8cm}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (point) at (0,0)[text width=16mm,align=center] {\textcolor{red-undar}{\A\textbf{}}};
\draw[line width=2pt,draw=red-undar] (0.1,5.3) -- ++(0,0.1)-- ++(-6.6,0) node[midway,above,text width=5.8cm,text centered,] {\textcolor{red-undar}{\A\textbf\centering{Cadencia Compuesta Disonante}}}-- ++(0,-0.1);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
|\en\bar%
\notes{\color{black}\zwh{G}\tsslur0{c}\hu{c}}|\zwh{g}\wh{k}\en%
\notes\hu{b}|\en\bar%
\notes\zhl{J}\hu{c}\zcharnote{-24}{\hspace{-1.7cm}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (point) at (0,0)[text width=16mm,align=center] {\textcolor{red-undar}{\A\textbf{}}};
\draw[line width=2pt,draw=red-undar] (0.1,5.3) -- ++(0,0.1)-- ++(-3.8,0) node[midway,above,text width=5.8cm,text centered,] {\textcolor{red-undar}{\A\textbf\centering{Cadencia Plagal}}}-- ++(0,-0.1);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
|\zhl{g}\hu{l}\en%
\notes\zhl{M}\hu{c}|\zhl{h}\hu{m}\en\bar%
\notes\zwh{J}\wh{e}|\zwh{g}\wh{l}\en\setdoubleBAR\alaligne%
\notes\zwh{G}\hu{b}\zcharnote{-24}{\hspace{-1.6cm}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (point) at (0,0)[text width=16mm,align=center] {\textcolor{red-undar}{\A\textbf{}}};
\draw[line width=2pt,draw=red-undar] (0.1,5.3) -- ++(0,0.1)-- ++(-7.1,0) node[midway,above,text width=5.8cm,text centered,] {\textcolor{red-undar}{\A\textbf\centering{Cadencia Doble}}}-- ++(0,-0.1);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
|\zwh{g}\hu{k}\en%
\notes\hu{c}|\hu{l}\en\bar%
\notes\zwh{G}\hu{c}|\zwh{g}\wh{k}\en%
\notes\hu{b}|\en\bar%
\notes\zhl{J}\hu{c}\zcharnote{-24}{\hspace{-1.8cm}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (point) at (0,0)[text width=16mm,align=center] {\textcolor{red-undar}{\A\textbf{}}};
\draw[line width=2pt,draw=red-undar] (0.1,5.3) -- ++(0,0.1)-- ++(-3.6,0) node[midway,above,text width=5.8cm,text centered,] {\textcolor{red-undar}{\A\textbf\centering{Cadencia Plagal}}}-- ++(0,-0.1);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
|\zhl{g}\hu{l}\en%
\notes\zhl{M}\hu{c}|\zhl{h}\hu{m}\en\bar%
\notes\zwh{J}\wh{c}|\zwh{g}\wh{l}\en\setdoubleBAR%
\nolyr%
\lyricsoff%
\endpiece
\end{music}
\end{document}

The current output is as follow:

The desired output is as follow:

Note that it is needed to reduce the vertical space between system.

I do not have a solution (yet), but I have seen that the space depends directly on the TikZ image inserted and therefore does not depend on \stafftopmarg nor on \staffbotmarg. Could you thing of a different indication of the node?

Maybe the problem is related to Tikz configuration...

I can not reproduce your output with you code. How do you compile?

@hpekristiansen There is a MusixTeX part in it, so you must musixflx your file after the first compilation to get an .mx2 file and then compile a second time.

There are several strange things in your code.
\node (point) at (0,0)[text width=16mm,align=center] {\textcolor{red-undar}{\A\textbf{}}};
Makes no sense - you name a node that you do not need, change the width, alignment, color and font of nothing. -all to make your tikzpicture larger.
You could do the same thing with \path (0,0); or add (0,0) to the next \draw.
Making the tikzpicture larger is exactly what you do not want. You want your picture to take up no space - use overlay. You can manually adjust the position with \hspace and baseline. Instead of manually adjusting you could probably reference the relevant things, but I do not know enough about music latex to do it.
\documentclass[border=1cm, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\input musixlyr
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\xdefinecolor{red-undar}{RGB}{179,35,79}
\begin{document}
\begin{music}
\hsize=\linewidth%
\font\A=phvb8t at 10pt% added for letter type.
\font\B=phvb8t at 13pt% added for letter type.
\resetlyrics
\setlyrics{Acordes}{\B V \B I \B IV \B I \B V\raisebox{-.1ex}{\bfseries\musFig[l]{6\,5 4\,3}} \empty{} \B I \B IV \B I \empty{} \B V\raisebox{-.1ex}{\bfseries\musFig[l]{4-3 5---}} \empty{} \B I \B IV \B I \B V\raisebox{-.1ex}{\bfseries\musFig[l]{5\,6 3\,4}} \empty{} \B V\raisebox{-.1ex}{\bfseries\musFig[l]{4-3 5---}} \empty{} \B I \B IV \B I}%
\setsongraise{1}{-0.3cm}
\parindent0mm
\sepbarrules
\instrumentnumber{1}%
\interstaff{12}%espacio entre pentagramas del piano
%\stafftopmarg0pt\staffbotmarg5\Interligne\relax%
\setclef16
\setstaffs12
\nobarnumbers
\startpiece
\A\assignlyricsmulti{1}{1}{Acordes}
\notes\hsk\zhl{G}\hu{b}\zcharnote{-24}{\hspace{1.7cm}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-5.3cm, overlay]
\draw[line width=2pt,draw=red-undar] (0.1,0) -- ++(0,0.1)-- ++(-4.1,0) node[midway,above,text width=2.5cm,text centered,] {\textcolor{red-undar}{\A\textbf\centering{Cadencia Perfecta}}}-- ++(0,-0.1);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
|\hsk\zhl{g}\hu{k}\en
\notes\zhl{J}\hu{c}|\zhl{g}\hu{l}\en\setdoublebar\bar%
\notes\zhl{M}\hu{c}\zcharnote{-24}{\hspace{2.9cm}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-5.3cm, overlay]
\draw[line width=2pt,draw=red-undar] (0.1,0) -- ++(0,0.1)-- ++(-6.1,0) node[midway,above = 0.15cm,text width=4.6cm,text centered,] {\textcolor{red-undar}{\A\textbf\centering{Cadencia Plagal}}}-- ++(0,-0.1);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
|\zhl{h}\hu{m}\en\bar%
\notes\zhl{J}\hu{c}|\zhl{g}\hu{l}\en\setdoubleBAR\alaligne%
\notes\zwh{G}\hu{e}\zcharnote{-24}{\hspace{3.2cm}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-5.3cm, overlay]
\draw[line width=2pt,draw=red-undar] (0.1,0) -- ++(0,0.1)-- ++(-5.1,0) node[midway,above,text width=5.8cm,text centered,] {\textcolor{red-undar}{\A\textbf\centering{Cadencia Compuesta\\ Consonante}}}-- ++(0,-0.1);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
|\zwh{g}\hu{j}\en%
\notes\hu{d}|\hu{i}\en\bar%
\notes\zhl{J}\hu{e}|\zhl{g}\hu{j}\en%
\notes\zhl{M}\hu{f}\zcharnote{-24}{\hspace{2.4cm}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-5.3cm, overlay]
\draw[line width=2pt,draw=red-undar] (0.1,0) -- ++(0,0.1)-- ++(-4.8,0) node[midway,above = 0.15cm,text width=5.8cm,text centered,] {\textcolor{red-undar}{\A\textbf\centering{Cadencia Plagal}}}-- ++(0,-0.1);
\end{tikzpicture}
}%
|\zhl{g}\hu{l}\en%
\notes\zhl{M}\hu{c}|\zhl{h}\hu{m}\en\bar%
\notes\zwh{J}\wh{c}|\zwh{g}\wh{l}\en\setdoubleBAR%
\nolyr%
\lyricsoff%
\endpiece
\end{music}
\end{document}



To see how large a tikzpicture is, you can add
\draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);

just before \end{tikzpicture}. With the overlay option, the tikzpicture takes up no space. Here is it shown for your original code:


Just for the MusiXTeX part: before the first \notes add space by \addspace{1\afterruleskip}%, - or less than 1, but this is the normal way to start a piece of music, delete \zcharnote{-24)(\hspace{1.7cm} and the closing }, start the line with the tikz picture with a baseline e.g. on -3.3cm, and set your first point more to the right, e.g. 3.6, after the picture write all notes of the measure, without the \hsk.

@C.Peters: I am confused. Was that comment meant for me? I have no idea how or any desire to do what you write. I just fixed the problem with TIkZ. -that is it.

I did not want to post an answer which just improves the entire code, because you solved the tikz problem. You suggested that there may be an other way of placing the picture inside music. This is what I did, to clean-up the code a bit more. Looking at the solution ABV placed to his own question, you can see that he does not always use the most effective solution - in this case using neither of our solutions.

The solved solutions has been done using: \useasboundingbox command.
The code is as follow:
\documentclass[%
border={1pt -30pt 2pt 3pt},% left bottom right top
%border=8pt
varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\input musixlyr
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\xdefinecolor{red-undar}{RGB}{179,35,79}
\begin{document}
\begin{music}
\hsize=\linewidth%
\font\A=phvb8t at 10pt% added for letter type.
\font\B=phvb8t at 13pt% added for letter type.
\resetlyrics
\setlyrics{Acordes}{\B V \B I \B IV \B I \B V\raisebox{-.1ex}{\bfseries\musFig[l]{6\,5 4\,3}} \empty{} \B I \B IV \B I \empty{} \B V\raisebox{-.1ex}{\bfseries\musFig[l]{4-3 5---}} \empty{} \B I \B IV \B I \B V\raisebox{-.1ex}{\bfseries\musFig[l]{5\,6 3\,4}} \empty{} \B V\raisebox{-.1ex}{\bfseries\musFig[l]{4-3 5---}} \empty{} \B I \B IV \B I}%
\setsongraise{1}{-0.3cm}
\parindent0mm
\sepbarrules
\instrumentnumber{1}%
\interstaff{12}%espacio entre pentagramas del piano
%\stafftopmarg0pt\staffbotmarg5\Interligne\relax%
\setclef16
\setstaffs12
\nobarnumbers
\startpiece
\A\assignlyricsmulti{1}{1}{Acordes}
\notes\hsk\zhl{G}\hu{b}\zcharnote{-12}{\hspace{-2.35cm}%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\useasboundingbox (0.2,0) rectangle (-4.1,5.4);
\node (point) at (0,0){};
\draw[line width=2pt,draw=red-undar] (0.1,4.4) -- ++(0,0.1)-- ++(-4.1,0) node[midway,above,text width=2.5cm,text centered,] {\textcolor{red-undar}{\A\textbf\centering{Cadencia Perfecta}}}-- ++(0,-0.1);
%\draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
|\hsk\zhl{g}\hu{k}\en
\notes\zhl{J}\hu{c}|\zhl{g}\hu{l}\en\setdoublebar\bar%
\notes\zhl{M}\hu{c}\zcharnote{-12}{\hspace{-3.1cm}%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\useasboundingbox (2.4,0) rectangle (-4.1,5.4);
\node (point) at (0,0)[text width=16mm,align=center] {\textcolor{red-undar}{\A\textbf{}}};
\draw[line width=2pt,draw=red-undar] (2.1,4.4) -- ++(0,0.1)-- ++(-6.1,0) node[midway,above = 0.15cm of point,text width=4.6cm,text centered,] {\textcolor{red-undar}{\A\textbf\centering{Cadencia Plagal}}}-- ++(0,-0.1);
%\draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
|\zhl{h}\hu{m}\en\bar%
\notes\zhl{J}\hu{c}|\zhl{g}\hu{l}\en\setdoubleBAR\alaligne%
\notes\zwh{G}\hu{e}\zcharnote{-12}{\hspace{-2.4cm}%
\begin{tikzpicture}%[baseline=-5.3cm, overlay]
\useasboundingbox (2.3,0) rectangle (-3.3,5.4);
\node (point) at (0,0)[text width=16mm,align=center] {\textcolor{red-undar}{\A\textbf{}}};
\draw[line width=2pt,draw=red-undar] (2.2,4.4) -- ++(0,0.1)-- ++(-5.1,0) node[midway,above,text width=5.8cm,text centered,] {\textcolor{red-undar}{\A\textbf\centering{Cadencia Compuesta\\ Consonante}}}-- ++(0,-0.1);
%\draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
|\zwh{g}\hu{j}\en%
\notes\hu{d}|\hu{i}\en\bar%
\notes\zhl{J}\hu{e}|\zhl{g}\hu{j}\en%
\notes\zhl{M}\hu{f}\zcharnote{-12}{\hspace{-2.9cm}%
\begin{tikzpicture}%[baseline=-5.3cm, overlay]
\useasboundingbox (3.6,0) rectangle (-2.1,5.4);
\node (point) at (0,0)[text width=16mm,align=center] {\textcolor{red-undar}{\A\textbf{}}};
\draw[line width=2pt,draw=red-undar] (3.2,4.4) -- ++(0,0.1)-- ++(-4.8,0) node[midway,above = 0.15cm of point,text width=5.8cm,text centered,] {\textcolor{red-undar}{\A\textbf\centering{Cadencia Plagal}}}-- ++(0,-0.1);
%\draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
|\zhl{h}\hu{j}\en\bar%
\notes\zwh{J}\wh{e}|\zwh{g}\wh{j}\en\setdoubleBAR\alaligne%
\notes\issluru0c\hu{c}\zcharnote{-12}{\hspace{-1.8cm}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\useasboundingbox (4.5,0) rectangle (-2.1,5.4);
\node (point) at (0,0)[text width=16mm,align=center] {\textcolor{red-undar}{\A\textbf{}}};
\draw[line width=2pt,draw=red-undar] (4.6,4.4) -- ++(0,0.1)-- ++(-6.6,0) node[midway,above,text width=5.8cm,text centered,] {\textcolor{red-undar}{\A\textbf\centering{Cadencia Compuesta Disonante}}}-- ++(0,-0.1);
%\draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
|\en\bar%
\notes{\color{black}\zwh{G}\tsslur0{c}\hu{c}}|\zwh{g}\wh{k}\en%
\notes\hu{b}|\en\bar%
\notes\zhl{J}\hu{c}\zcharnote{-12}{\hspace{-1.7cm}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\useasboundingbox (3.1,0) rectangle (-2.1,5.4);
\node (point) at (0,0)[text width=16mm,align=center] {\textcolor{red-undar}{\A\textbf{}}};
\draw[line width=2pt,draw=red-undar] (3.0,4.4) -- ++(0,0.1)-- ++(-3.8,0) node[midway,above,text width=5.8cm,text centered,] {\textcolor{red-undar}{\A\textbf\centering{Cadencia Plagal}}}-- ++(0,-0.1);
%\draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
|\zhl{g}\hu{l}\en%
\notes\zhl{M}\hu{c}|\zhl{h}\hu{m}\en\bar%
\notes\zwh{J}\wh{e}|\zwh{g}\wh{l}\en\setdoubleBAR\alaligne%
\notes\zwh{G}\hu{b}\zcharnote{-24}{\hspace{-1.6cm}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (point) at (0,0)[text width=16mm,align=center] {\textcolor{red-undar}{\A\textbf{}}};
\draw[line width=2pt,draw=red-undar] (0.1,5.3) -- ++(0,0.1)-- ++(-7.1,0) node[midway,above,text width=5.8cm,text centered,] {\textcolor{red-undar}{\A\textbf\centering{Cadencia Doble}}}-- ++(0,-0.1);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
|\zwh{g}\hu{k}\en%
\notes\hu{c}|\hu{l}\en\bar%
\notes\zwh{G}\hu{c}|\zwh{g}\wh{k}\en%
\notes\hu{b}|\en\bar%
\notes\zhl{J}\hu{c}\zcharnote{-24}{\hspace{-1.8cm}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (point) at (0,0)[text width=16mm,align=center] {\textcolor{red-undar}{\A\textbf{}}};
\draw[line width=2pt,draw=red-undar] (0.1,5.3) -- ++(0,0.1)-- ++(-3.6,0) node[midway,above,text width=5.8cm,text centered,] {\textcolor{red-undar}{\A\textbf\centering{Cadencia Plagal}}}-- ++(0,-0.1);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
|\zhl{g}\hu{l}\en%
\notes\zhl{M}\hu{c}|\zhl{h}\hu{m}\en\bar%
\notes\zwh{J}\wh{c}|\zwh{g}\wh{l}\en\setdoubleBAR%
\nolyr%
\lyricsoff%
\endpiece
\end{music}
\end{document}

The output is as follow:

